# GCM gives same registration_id multiple times

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Today I tried to get a registration_id from gcm services.
It worked fine. But every time when I uninstall my app
(that includes deleting all shared preferences for that app)
and reinstalled the app to get a new registration_id, I got 
the exact same registration_id. That happened now 5 times 
so I guess there is something wrong. Or is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal. GCM usually doesn't generate a new Registration ID for the same application and the same device.

The only way I managed to get a new Registration ID for the same app and the same device was to uninstall the app, send several messages to the old Registration ID until I got a NotRegistered error, and only then install the app again.

Comment: Yes here too, because probably google invalidates a Reg id when you try to send a message to an unused.